# How can I decode .pcv files?

Tags: decode

Is there any way to decode these kind of files? Is there any program? I know I can install these files with mozbackup, but I want to see the sourcecode, if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are zip files so you can read them as that.

Src: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=1834495